# JavaScript heap out of memory - nodejs and postman

Tags: node.js, heap-memory

I'm using newman to run postman tests in a nodejs app (v10.15.3). There are 4 separate postman collections. I can run any of them individually without issue but when running them is series, either one at a time in the postman runner or in bitbucket pipelines they fail about two thirds through with the exception below:

```
0: ExitFrame [pc: 000000B11D95FFA0]
Security context: 0x033905f9e6e9 <JSObject>
    1: stringSlice(aka stringSlice) [000000D8B3E918F9] [buffer.js:~589] [pc=000000B11DB367AF](this=0x03d7545026f1 <undefined>,buf=0x028296882379 <Uint8Array
map = 0000039C9AD52F31>,encoding=0x033905fbe311 <String[4]: utf8>,start=0,end=13747055)
    2: toString [000003A6F311ED59] [buffer.js:~643] [pc=000000B11DB2F0AA](this=0x028296882379 <Uint8Array map = 0...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 00007FF7FE7BF04A v8::internal::GCIdleTimeHandler::GCIdleTimeHandler+5114
 2: 00007FF7FE79A0C6 node::MakeCallback+4518
 3: 00007FF7FE79AA30 node_module_register+2032
 4: 00007FF7FEA220EE v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory+846
 5: 00007FF7FEA2201F v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory+639
 6: 00007FF7FEF42BC4 v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor+9556
 7: 00007FF7FEF410CB v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor+2651
 8: 00007FF7FEAFCA3B v8::internal::Factory::AllocateRawWithImmortalMap+59
 9: 00007FF7FEAFF4ED v8::internal::Factory::NewRawTwoByteString+77
10: 00007FF7FEAFE67E v8::internal::Factory::NewStringFromUtf8+238
11: 00007FF7FEA3D8FB v8::String::NewFromUtf8+363
12: 00007FF7FE7884C1 node::Buffer::New+24225
13: 000000B11D95FFA0
```

I've tried setting --max_old_space_size base on some threads I've read but that doesn't fix the issue. I've also removed any console.log() entries. The postman console reports Error: read ECONNRESET, which seems to imply we are losing connectivity to the db I assume but perhaps this is a victim of the memory exception. The process is using the serverless framework including mongodb-memory-server which is loaded via json on start so no records or collections are overly large but each test does connect and there are several hundred tests. This has been working fine for a long time so perhaps we've just reached some threshold with a recent change but I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this. Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: I don't know how we could help without seeing and understanding how your code is using memory.

Comment: Understood. Its a very large code base so its difficult to give the full picture. I was really looking for general ideas on how to troubleshoot, like how to go about finding where a memory leak could be. The trace above is from the code but in the postman console I get a different error (econnreset) and in bitbucket pipeline I get something else (socket hang up and then econnrefused). I assume the trace above is the most accurate... just not sure how to trace memory issues.